# Uploading build for internal testers on TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am facing a problem while uploading test build for internal testers on TestFlight. I have admin role on developer account and app manager on iTunesConnect.  The problem is that the upload process freezes while showing a message "validating application".

I have also set the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption to false on info.plist and I am using automatic provisioning profile for creating build.

I am following this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224)

Comment: How do you know it freezes? In my case it just takes so long it looks like something is wrong, but eventually after 30 minutes the upload actually starts and in 1 hour it finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these items before uploading build for test flight

1. Application profile (Beta testing) is created on iTunes Connect.
2. you have Developer or higher role on iTunes connect If member of a team.
3. you have admin or agent role in apple developer account if you are a member of a team
4. If not using encryption set ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption to false in info.plist
5. If supporting iOS 7.0 you need to add Launch images in info.plist
6. Set provision profile to automatic and set certificate to don't code sign.

Comment: Thanks Kapil, adding launch images to info.plist worked for me.